# Effaceability conditions in the derived category

Tags: homological-algebra, constructible-sheaves

In abelian categories effaceability of functors is often an interesting property.

Is there any general equivalent condition on derived functors in the derived category?

For example, for a functor in the category on constructible sheaves, can effaceability be detected in the derived category of constructible sheaves?